# Chapter number and name on separate lines using titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc, titleps

I was wanting to use titletoc to put the chapter number and title on different lines in the table of contents.  If I were to type the ToC out manually, then I would type something along the lines of `\centerline{\scshape Chapter 1}\newline` and `\centerline{\uppercase Name of the first chapter}` to obtain my desired result.  I attempted to use `\titlecontents`, but have been running into some problems.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I should approach this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{dsfont, amssymb, latexsym, graphicx, amsfonts, amsmath, booktabs, mathtools, amsthm, geometry, environ, multicol, subfiles, titlesec, titletoc, mathrsfs}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

\titlespacing{\section}{18pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{8pt}{}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{18pt}{0pt}{12pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont}{\centering\small{CHAPTER \thechapter}}{4pt}{\centering\uppercase}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}

\dottedcontents{section}[3.8em]{}{2.3em}{0.8pc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\normalfont}{\centering\scshape Chapter \thechapter}{}{\centering\uppercase}

\begin{document}
Titlepage
    \newpage
\tableofcontents
    \newpage
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First section}
abc
\section{Second section}
abc

\chapter{Preliminary lemmata}
\section{First section}
abc
\section{Second section}
abc

\chapter{Proof of the main assertion}
\section{First section}
abc
\section{Second section}
abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you show us the `titletoc` code you tried, and we can help you fix that.

Comment: I tried ```\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\normalfont}{\centering\scshape Chapter \thechapter}{}{\centering\uppercase}```.

Comment: Thanks, but rather than put a code fragment in the comments, edit your question to show a small compilable document people can play with.

Comment: Thanks. If you're making such changes to the sectioning commands with `titlesec` it's really not a good idea to use a class like `amsbook`. Use the plain `book` class and work from there. There's an example of a centred two line toc entry in §6.5 of the `titlesec` documentation, but it doesn't work with `amsbook`.

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  With a bit of fiddling around with the example from \S6.5 I was able to get it exactly as I wanted.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. It would be helpful to others if you added an answer showing what you did.